# How to change "Time Grain" in Superset

Tags: time-series, apache-superset

I am trying to create a time series chart in Superset using a field named "created_at" which is a timestamp. But in the Superset interface, I can't change the "Time Grain" at all but created_at was picked up automatically.

[image]

Any idea how to resolve this issue? I wanted to draw a daily timeseries chart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a connection string issue. postgresql+psycopg2 should be used instead of postgresql